# Structure of the space of holomorphic structure on a vector bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, connections, holomorphic-bundles

It is well known that the space of connections on a vector bundle $E\rightarrow X$ is an affine space modeled on $\Omega^1(X,End(E))$.

Let $Dol(E)$ denote the space of holomorphic structures $\bar{\partial}_E$ on $E$. We easily see  from the Leibniz rule
$$\bar{\partial}_E(fs)=\bar{\partial}f\cdot s + f\bar{\partial}_Es$$
that the difference between two holomorphic structures $\bar{\partial}^1_E-\bar{\partial}^2_E$ is a tensor that belongs to $\Omega^{0,1}(X,End(E))$. Moreover, there is a flatness condition
$$\bar{\partial}_E\circ \bar{\partial}_E=0$$
which implies that  $Dol(E)$ is not affine.

What can we say anyway on the tangent space of $Dol(E)$ as a subspace of $\Omega^{0,1}(X,End(E))$?

Comment: I don’t know the details, but it would appear that the tangent space is given by a linear PDE. $\dot T\in\Omega^{0,1}(X,End(E))$ lies in the tangent space at $\bar\partial_E$ if and only if there exists a curve $T(t)$ such that $T(0)=0$, $T’(0)=\dot T$, and $(\bar\partial_E + T(t))^2 = 0$. Now differentiate the last equation with respect to $t$ and set $t$ to $0$.